# How to resample Pandas data frame without grouping datetime in the result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, resampling, candlestick-chart

I'm trying to resample a data frame for **last 30 seconds** in **Pandas** in order to calculate **OHLC** of a candle stick.

I'm using Pandas and SQLite.

Data Structure is : _DateTime , _Price

The Problem is when my last 30 seconds data belong to the different datetime(minute) the result will have more than 1 row !

**My Code :**

```
con = sqlite3.connect('Pices.db')

_Sql_Query : str = "select _DateTime , _Price from _prices where datetime(_DateTime) >= '" + 
datetime.strftime(datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=30),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + "'"

df = pd.read_sql_query(_Sql_Query,con,parse_dates=True)

con.close()

df['_DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['_DateTime'])

df = df.resample('30S',on='_DateTime')['_Price'].ohlc().dropna()


print(df)
```

**The Result :**

```
2020-11-28 10:03:30  5306000.0  5306000.0  5306000.0  5306000.0
2020-11-28 10:04:00  5306000.0  5306000.0  5306000.0  5306000.0
```

Now , how can I resample just the **Last 30 seconds** of my data no matter what _DateTime it belongs to.

I need to be just 1 row in the result of my Last 30 seconds.

Best Regards.

Comment: You need something like a rolling window, I would advice filter data for last 30 secs, and drop the date column after that. Then compute the metric you need `ohlc`.

Comment: @vikash-singh Would you please show me an example ?